# Science fiction movie involving a woman who steals information about a crashed alien spaceship and is hunted by a powerful company

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, space

I'm looking for a science fiction movie, probably from the 1980s, that I saw as a child.

The plot starts with a woman (maybe a cyborg) stealing a suitcase/box from a rival company (Norwegian Interspace or Interways?) containing information about a crashed alien space ship. The scene happens at a space port.

Then the woman goes rogue, maybe. She is hunted by some powerful company. Its boss is a Japanese guy, I guess. He commands a large space ship with fighters attached to it on long docking mechanisms. The ship is destroyed during a fight, because the boss orders the launch of a nuclear weapon, but ordered its ignition too close to the ship.

At the end, the woman is in the interior of the crashed alien space ship, seeing  stars or the shape of a galaxy.

Answer (score 12):

Is this ***[Beyond the Rising Moon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092648/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (1987), also known as *Star Quest*, also known as *Outerworld*...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_the_Rising_Moon):

> *Beyond the Rising Moon* (also known as *Star Quest* and *Starquest - Beyond the Rising Moon*) is a 1988 direct-to-video science fiction film by Philip J. Cook.

From IMDB:

> An alien spaceship is being sought by various factions on Earth. A female cyborg and a rogue trader team up to stop evil forces from taking over the ship.

Set in the year 2074, the film centres on a race to claim an abandoned alien spaceship on an unexplored planet named Elysium.

The primary protagonist is Pentan, a genetically engineered woman with enhanced strength and intelligence created by Kuriyama Enterprises for the purpose of corporate warfare.

The primary antagonists are the head of Kuriyama Enterprises, Takashi Kuriyama, and his second-in-command, John Moesby.

> [image: Image of Takashi Kuriyama and John Moesby, from "Beyond the Rising Moon" (1987).]
>
> <sub>*Beyond the Rising Moon* (1987)</sub>

Moesby orders Pentan to steal a tape containing information on the location of the alien vessel from couriers working for a rival corporation, Norwegian Interworld.

She successfully intercepts the couriers in Star City in North Africa and steals the tape, but rather than bring it to Moesby as ordered, she hires Harold Brickman -- the owner of a small spacecraft -- to take her to Elysium, so that she can claim the alien vessel herself and use it to buy her freedom. From this point, Brickman serves as a secondary protagonist.

When Pentan and Brickman reach Elysium, they enter the alien vessel and see an image of a galaxy projected in its interior.

> [image: Image of the interior of an alien vessel, from "Beyond the Rising Moon" (1987).]
>
> <sub>*Beyond the Rising Moon* (1987)</sub>

They're subsequently confronted by Kuriyama and his subordinates, who've followed them in the Promethean, a large cargo ship with eight small fighter ships called Tulwars docked on its exterior.

> [image: Image of the Promethean, from "Beyond the Rising Moon" (1987).]
>
> <sub>*Beyond the Rising Moon* (1987)</sub>

Pentan manages to hijack one of the Tulwars, and uses it to destroy most of the others. The pilot of the last remaining Tulwar decides to hightail it back to the Promethean, but Kuriyama orders the Promethean to fire a torpedo at the Tulwar, detonating a three-megaton warhead on it that destroys them both.

In the closing minutes of the film, Brickman reenters the alien vessel and sees the projected image of the galaxy again.

Comment: According to a making of documentary I found on YouTube, the version of the film titled _Outerworld_ is a newer edit made for the DVD release, with certain scenes removed or shortened to quicken the pacing, and some of the weaker special effects replaced by more modern CGI. The film was shot on less than $200,000, so some of the original effects were apparently very poor. I also found [this page](http://eaglefilms.com/despiser/Outerworld.htm) that contains more information about the film and several images.

Comment: Yes, it's Beyond the Rising Moon. Thank you very much!

Comment: "What if you weren't human, but a genetically engineered assassin, and your employers were after you?" <- Haven't all wondered about that at one time or another...

Comment: @TheSeeker - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.